# Accessing Data stored in an object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, object

I am trying to access the "name" out of my object, however i am having no luck in finding a solution. My end goal is to access the file name and then use it to display the image. However i am having no luck getting the actual name out.

This is the object that i am trying to access data from:

```
{
     "file-0": {
        "name": "2012-11-23-JokeExplanationCorner.jpg",
        "type": "image\/jpeg",
        "tmp_name": "C:\\xampp2\\tmp\\phpA93E.tmp",
        "error": 0,
        "size": 378086
       },
        "file-1": {
        "name": "11039919_10206003688989240_2065769962_n.jpg",
        "type": "image\/jpeg",
        "tmp_name": "C:\\xampp2\\tmp\\phpA940.tmp",
        "error": 0,
        "size": 143703
   }
}
```

This is the php which produces the file: If there's a better way of doing this which will make it easier I am open to suggestions:

```
$sFileName = "imgDB.txt";

for($i=0 ; $i<count($_FILES) ; $i++){
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file-'.$i]['tmp_name'] , "img/". $_FILES['file-
'.$i]['name'] );
}

$_FILES = json_encode($_FILES, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
file_put_contents($sFileName, $_FILES);
```

And finally this is the JS that sort of works. It is getting the file name, but i cant get it to go another level lower and console.log all the names of the imgs within the files.

```
$.getJSON( "imgDB.txt" , function( jData ) {
     console.log("getJSON called for images");

    for (var name in jData) {
         if (jData.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            console.log(" name is = " + name);
            console.log("jData = " + jData);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use a `.json` file instead of `.txt`

Comment: And you need to make sure you go into `jData.file-0` first

Comment: console.log(jData) and show here output

Comment: The two console.log's at the end of my JS produce:

   `name is = file-1`
     `jData = [object Object]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Js Snippet.

```js
var Jdata = {
         "file-0": {
            "name": "2012-11-23-JokeExplanationCorner.jpg",
            "type": "image\/jpeg",
            "tmp_name": "C:\\xampp2\\tmp\\phpA93E.tmp",
            "error": 0,
            "size": 378086
           },
            "file-1": {
            "name": "11039919_10206003688989240_2065769962_n.jpg",
            "type": "image\/jpeg",
            "tmp_name": "C:\\xampp2\\tmp\\phpA940.tmp",
            "error": 0,
            "size": 143703
       }
    }
    var length = Object.keys(Jdata).length;
    for (var i=0; i< length; i++) {
            console.log(" name is = " + Jdata['file-'+i]['name']);
        }
```